# Wrap <li></li> with a link with css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to wrap the items of my menu with a link but I can not get to do it. I tried several way but doesn't work. Can someone help me, please?

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/andresgl/4y795fLa/1/

```css
body {
    background: blue;
}

.main-nav {
    display: flex;
}

.main-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}

.main-nav ul li {
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
.main-nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #bcd22c;
}

.logo img {
    width: 35%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 420px) {
    body {
        background: purple;
    }

    .main-nav ul {
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;

    }

    .main-nav ul li {
        display: flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .logo img {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .main-nav-item-link {
        position: relative;
    }

    .main-nav-item-link a {
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="main-nav-item logo">
                <figure>
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.qubesoft.com/images/bbc-logo.gif" alt=""></a>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <li class="main-nav-item"><div class="main-nav-item-link"><a href="#">Lorem Item 1</a></div></li>
            <li class="main-nav-item"><div class="main-nav-item-link"><a href="#">Lorem Item 2 ipsum</a></div></li>
            <li class="main-nav-item"><div class="main-nav-item-link"><a href="#">Lorem Item 3</a></div></li>
            <li class="main-nav-item"><div class="main-nav-item-link"><a href="#">Lorem Item 4</a></div></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

And here two images to see the problem that I have when i make hover should cover all parent item:

[image]

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any code trying to wrap `li` in `a` (which would be a bad idea, as it would result in an invalid DOM). I see markup and CSS rules, but no code. The markup I see already has `a` elements *inside* the `li`s (where they belong); what is the question exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @T.J. Crowder. Maybe I explained wrong. I would like   make the white area clickable too. not only the text line. Thank you!

Comment: Move the `<figure>` tag inside `<a>`: http://jsfiddle.net/4y795fLa/6/

Comment: and with the rest items? If i put the li elements inside the a elements works but it's not semantically correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me

.html file

```
<header>    
    <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <a href="#">
            <li class="main-nav-item logo">
                <figure><img src="http://www.qubesoft.com/images/bbc-logo.gif" alt="">
                </figure>
            </li>       </a>    
            <a href="#"><li class="main-nav-item"><div class="main-nav-item-link">Lorem Item 1</div></li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="main-nav-item"><div class="main-nav-item-link">Lorem Item 2 ipsum</div></li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="main-nav-item"><div class="main-nav-item-link">Lorem Item 3</div></li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="main-nav-item"><div class="main-nav-item-link">Lorem Item 4</div></li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

and .css file

```
body {
    background: blue;
}

figure {
    margin: 0;
}

.main-nav {
    display: flex;
}

    .main-nav ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .main-nav ul a {
        background: #fff;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 99px;
        max-height: 99px;
    }

    .main-nav ul a li  {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
    .main-nav ul a:hover {
        background: #bcd22c;
    }

    .logo img {
        width: 35%;
    }

@media screen and (min-width: 420px) { 
    body {
        background: purple;
    }

    .main-nav ul {
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;

    }

    .main-nav ul li {
        display: flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content: center;
    }   

    .logo img {
        width: 50%;
        margin-top: 25%;
    }

    .main-nav-item-link {
        position: relative;
    }

    .main-nav-item-link a {
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: but you are covering the li element with the a element and it's not correct. http://i.imgur.com/lJgucIn.jpg Thank you!

Comment: If you want only change backgroud color for li at the hover, it's very easy, you can use `.main-nav li:hover {
  background: #bcd22c;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Did you also try this

//css

```
li.main-nav-item:hover{put your styles here}
```

//html

```
<li class="main-nav-item"></li>
```

Comment: Yes, I though it but if it´s possible do it with css.. I prefer css. Thank you!

Comment: Not because with your solution won't be clickable the whole area. Only will change color. The a element have to cover all white area. Thank you!

Comment: so you want to achieve this with just css? good luck. I will keep an eye on this question. I am interested how you solve it.